# How to save the contents of a for loop in a variable

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

Hey so i have a program here that reads into a CSV file which i created earlier

```
import csv
import psycopg2
with open('C:\\Users\\Danis Porovic\\PycharmProjects\\Module1\\berichten.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line)
```

the for loop gives this as a result

```
['vies', 'Mon 07 Nov 2022 18:43', 'Mia', 'Haarlem']
['vies', 'Mon 07 Nov 2022 18:43', 'Mia', 'Amsterdam']
['vies', 'Mon 07 Nov 2022 18:43', 'Mia', 'Sittard']
['vies', 'Mon 07 Nov 2022 18:43', 'Mia', 'Venlo']
['vies', 'Mon 07 Nov 2022 18:43', 'Mia', 'Helmond']
['Het zou wel wat schoner mogen zijn', 'Tue 08 Nov 2022 00:49', 'Tijmen', 'Hilversum']
['Het zou wel wat schoner mogen zijn', 'Tue 08 Nov 2022 00:49', 'anoniem', 'Roosendaal']
```

Now how could i save all this information from the for loop in a single variable?

Comment: Create a new list before you start the loop, and append the line to the list on each iteration.

Comment: You create a list and append each row to a list.

Comment: `lines = list(csv.reader(csv_file))`.  No `for` loop required and this will give you a list of rows.

Comment: `lines = list(csv.reader(csv_file))` is definitely the way to go. Solid answer @Mark Tolonen

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```py
result = []
for line in csv_reader:
    result.append(line)
```

Or using list comprehension:

```py
result = [line for line in csv_reader]
```

**Edit:** After comments outlining in more detail what you're looking for. We can transpose the list you usually get so each sublist represents a *column* from the .csv rather than a row:

```py
import csv
with open('a.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    regular_list = list(csv.reader(csv_file))
    transposed_result = list(map(list, zip(*regular_list)))
    print(transposed_result)
```

Shoutout to @Mark Tolonen for removing the for loop iteration and jumping right to `csv.reader(csv_file)`

Comment: The method above did display all the information but not in the way i want it to. I would like to have each line as a list. This so i can use indexing on it later.

Comment: We currently have a list of lists, where the sublist has many strings. Were you still hoping for a list of lists, but in a different format? Say... the first list is ['vies', 'vies', etc.]? Or did you want a single list, where we've concatenated the sublist into single strings? What did you have in mind in particular?

Comment: The CSV files is structured in this way:
'Message', Date and Time', 'Name', 'Station'
I would like to save the information from the for loop in a variable so that i can use indexing on the list later on and grab all the messages for instance. So for every line create a list with 4 strings in it

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. We currently have list, where each item is a list with 4 strings which allows for indexing. When you say 'variable' do you mean dictionary? If so that'd allow you to look up values e.g. `result[0]["Message"]` would output "vies". Right not `result[0][0]` outputs "vies"

Comment: I would like to have a variable contain the exact information which i gathered with the for loop. So that with index[0] i can get all the messages, with index[1] all the dates, with index[2] all the names etc.

Comment: @danxs sounds like you want the lines transposed.  `zip` can be used for that.  `index = list(zip(*csv.reader(csv_file)))`

Comment: Updated my answer to get column-wise sublists

Comment: By the way i plan to use the csv file to send the messages to a postgresql database. Could there be any problems with the zip method if i try to send it to a database? I thought the best way was to use indexing but is there maybe a better way? @MarkTolonen

Comment: @Danxs If you're putting it in a database I wouldn't transpose the rows.  Databases have ways to query columns.